# Laravel: Sending Mail with Queue ignores Locale

Tags: email, laravel-5, queue

My Email template looks like this:

```
@component('mail::message')
# {{ $helloUser }}

@lang('welcome.message')
```

This

```
\App::setLocale('de);

$activeMail =  new \App\Mail\Register\Activate($user);

\Mail::to($user)->send($activeMail);
```

will send an mail with German text.

However, when I use a queue

```
\App::setLocale('de);

$activeMail =  new \App\Mail\Register\Activate($user);

\Mail::to($user)->queue($activeMail);
```

The mail is send in English, which is the default language of my app.
How can I send a message in German with the queue without changing the default language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Laravel 5.6. the `Mailable` class has gotten a `locale` method to care for this:

```
$activeMail =  new \App\Mail\Register\Activate($user);
$locale     =  $user->lang; // de 

\Mail::to($user)->locale($locale)->queue($activeMail);
```

---

For Laravel < 5.6 one could save the text in the mail object

```
class Activate extends Mailable
{

  public $mainText

  public function __construct()
  {
     $this->mainText = __('welcome.message');
  }
}
```

and change the template to

```
@component('mail::message')
# {{ $helloUser }}

{{$mainText}}
```

The difference is that `$mainText` is the string from the language when the mail object was created, while `@lang('welcome.message')` would be the string of the default language from your app.

Answer (score -1):

Since Laravel 5.7, there's something that can help you with that. Take a look at [Localizing Mailables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mail#localizing-mailables) in the documentation.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Translation\HasLocalePreference;

class User extends Model implements HasLocalePreference
{
    /**
     * Get the user's preferred locale.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function preferredLocale()
    {
        return $this->locale;
    }
}
```

Comment: The locale is actually saved in the user. But how do you pass the locale to the job?

Comment: The job checks if the class has the HasLocalePreference and grabs the preferredLocale() to set the language of the application for that job.